# new off-topic closing reason : programming assignment

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, homework

I would like to suggest a new closing reason to be added under "off-topic" : `programming assignment`

This should be used for questions where the person asking it clearly just pastes his/her homework assignment as a question on SO, or at least only provides the reader with a description of the task which has to be programmed - without any hint of an attempt at programming by themselves.

In my opinion this is a frequently occurring issue in posts, yet the choice for closing reasons in these cases is currently a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 34):

This is already covered under "Too broad", "Why isn't this code working" and in a smaller fashion "Unclear what you're asking".

There is no need for a separate reason.

PS: just because it's a programming assignment doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: Your answer could be limited to the `PS` and you'd get a +1 from me.

Comment: Being a programming assignment isn't a bad question, if they're looking for minor help-  they've coded something and are trying to debug it.  Someone looking to have their homework done for them (or mostly done for them) is a reason to close in my opinion.

Comment: @GabeSechan: no, the actual reason you're closing it then is because someone wants their *work* done for you, not just their *homework*. It makes no sense to single out "homework" questions when "work" questions are already covered under the reasons I mention above.

Comment: P.S Homework questions are good only if they are from good books. The quality of these homework questions really raise doubts about the quality of the books they use to learn programming :|

Comment: in my original question I am also not focusing on homework in particular (I just gave it as an example, since there are many of this particular kind), but I mean in general situations where the asker only supplies a task or goal to be achieved, and so basically "assigns" a programming task to the reader. I agree they can sort-of be captured under the three categories you mention - which are the ones I also usually use - but still my issue remains that such questions do not strictly or uniquely fall under any of them...

Comment: You can't invent a reason for every type of offtopic question; "Too broad" fits it just fine considering you're leaving the answerers with a greenfield: they can approach the solution in any way they can think off instead of reducing them to what the question went with in itself already.

Comment: I would like to see a note under "too broad" that says "by the way, in case it weren't obvious, questions that ask for answerers to write an entire program are too broad [you numbskull]" I'm only halfway joking ;)

Comment: well, to be clear, I do see your point, from a purely categorization viewpoint - though I think the closing reasons for questions also serve an important additional purpose: of sending a message to the person who posted it... saying it is "too broad" is not quite as  strong as saying "stop asking us to solve your problem without you thinking about it at all"

Comment: @MultiVAC Why shouldn't we say that? If someone asks a question that is insulting to the reader (implying that the reader's time is less valuable), why should we coddle the OP with circumspect euphemisms?