# Can we have a homework close reason on the "off-topic" close reason submenu?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, homework

Note: I am aware of the [previous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250867/close-reason-suggestion-closing-a-question-where-the-asker-wants-others-to-do-h) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260334/new-off-topic-closing-reason-programming-assignment) about this, but I'm not suggesting that all homework-related questions should be closed willy-nilly, nor that "homework" should be a top-level close reason. Also, the suggestions in answers to those previous questions to close homework as "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" don't apply to the case I'm talking about here.

Specifically, I'm asking about no-effort homework questions where the asker has just copy-pasted their assignment question as-is. One of the available close reasons is:

> **off-topic because...**
>   This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

and in the help center, it specifically lists the following as a type of off-topic question:

> 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

So in the case of a "do my homework" question where the asker has just posted their assignment verbatim, it seems pretty clear that voting to close is justified, and "off-topic" is the correct close reason.

However, when you click off-topic, you get a list of options, none of which really fit the homework case:

- Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.
- Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.
- Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
- Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

Of these, *"Questions seeking debugging help..."* seems the closest, but it still doesn't really fit the homework case because if they had provided code to be debugged, then it wouldn't have been off-topic according to (3) above.

Clicking "Other" requires you to write a justification that gets left as a comment, which seems unnecessary because it's such a common close reason.

Can we please add *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* to the list of off-topic close reasons?

Edit:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different

The linked question asks what the policy is on closing homework questions, whereas this question is asking for a new option in the off-topic question close vote interface. Regardless of the policy (whether the cited help center text is to be considered a rule or a guideline), it would convenient if the options supplied for closing off-topic questions more closely matched the rules/guidelines (whatever they may be) that we are instructed to follow when deciding whether to close them.

There are only 6 common reasons listed on the help center page, why not make each of them an option, plus an "other..." option?

Comment: Just go with "unclear" or a more detailed custom one, if it isn't clear what the askers problem with his task is.

Comment: If a homework question is off topic it is for a variety of reasons that we already can close for. I fail to see why there needs to be a new reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator usually it's completely clear what the question is because whoever set the homework has defined it concisely. It's also usually not "too broad" because homework assignments are usually a specific problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters which of the listed off-topic reasons apply? The questions don't belong on another stackexchange site, and they aren't asking for recommendations or debugging help. The only option left is "Other".

Comment: @samgak: Usually they are unclear; we don't know what help they need with specific code. Or they are too broad; explaining how they can solve their problem can take a whole book by the time you are done.

Comment: @samgak: and sometimes they are just terrible questions that may be on-topic, but you then *downvote* the post. Not everything has to be closed just because we don't feel it deserves an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with your point w/r/t to homework questions *in general* but in the case where the assignment question is just posted as-is, the help center is pretty clear that that is off-topic. And the close dialog is pretty clear in stating that we should go by what the help center defines as off topic when making the call.

Comment: So how are questions posting the homework assignment verbatim any different from any other question with a set of requirements? Those are just as off-topic. The OP may claim it is not really homework; they are just doing a course online, or studying a book at home, or just want you to do their paid work for them. The *motivation* for asking the question should be left out of the equation here; it doesn't *matter* that the question is posted because it was homework or any other reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters They are different from other questions because the help center and close dialog text singles out homework questions as requiring some work to have been done before asking a question and defines them as off-topic and close-able otherwise. The same isn't the case for non-homework questions, beyond general community WHYT guidelines. If we aren't supposed to treat them any differently then perhaps the help center text should be changed?

Comment: Yes, the help center text may have to be changed; it is general advice, not a specific off-topic close reason. Homework questions fit into the existing close reasons just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If there's an otherwise good question (not necessarily homework), but the OP clearly hasn't even considered the possibility of trying anything, would you say it's a good fit for the site and should be encouraged? [The tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) lists that in the "Don't ask about" section, the help center seems to say it's not enough, and I don't really want to be some kid's code writing service. Can you clarify?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you referenced the other post in your question now that it is reopened: [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255477)

Comment: @tux3: that'd be a *no effort* question, for which the discussion is here: [Should we add a "Do my work for me" close reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630)

Comment: I really don't this is a problem with homework questions.  Either they are on-topic (and answerable) or they're not.  And besides, who really wants to do _someone else's homework_?  In my experience for "bad" homework questions, downvotes + comments like "what have you tried" or "we won't do your homework" have a great way of pushing the question away and even removed/deleted from the following flood of downvotes.

Comment: I agree 100% with everything @MartijnPieters has said here.  Stop worrying about the OP.  Worry about the question.  Is it useful?  Is the problem a legitimate issue that someone could have in the real world?  Will it help someone else with the same problem?  If so, then there is absolutely no reason to close it just because it is homework.  The problem is if you give people a close reason, it will be over-used.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not suggesting that questions be closed just because they are homework and I specifically mentioned that. I'm talking about homework questions that don't show any previous effort, which is specifically defined as off topic. All of the other off topic reasons have corresponding close reasons except for the no effort homework one.

Comment: @samgak I know, which is why that isn't an answer.  But the last sentence of my comment is vital.  If you provide it, it will be used, mis-used, and over-used.  While there may be subset of questions that this could be used for, it is inherently bad because 99% of the time another close reason is appropriate.

Comment: "Specifically, I'm asking about no-effort homework questions where the asker has just copy-pasted their assignment question as-is." This is entirely answered in my answer in one of the questions you linked. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260337/1864167

Comment: @JeroenVannevel None of those reasons fit. Homework questions are usually neither too broad or unclear as to what the asker is asking, they are often specific questions posed in a clear way by the instructor. "Why isn't this code working" obviously doesn't apply if they haven't posted any code.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I disagree that another close reason is appropriate in 99% of the time, unless you are willing to be vague and imprecise. Usually, it's not. Also, closing homework questions for not showing prior effort already exists as a close reason right now, we are just being told to file them under "too broad" or some other inaccurate reason. So why not let us vote to close them under their *actual* reason? I wouldn't mind if a specific homework reason didn't exist if it wasn't for the fact that selecting "off-topic" (unlike "too broad") forces you to choose an answer from a submenu.

Comment: Years later, I was going to ask the same thing. Fortunately, I found your question which expressed my sentiments exactly. Why can we close for all of the reasons in the help center except for this one?

Comment: @Chipster After asking several questions like this I gave up on trying to put forward suggestions. A lot of these debates were "settled" years ago and the old-timers here don't want to revisit them or hear any new opinions. After a while it's just like banging your head against a brick wall so it's time to give up and cut back participation, it's just a website after all.

Answer (score 7):

"Homework" questions can be interpreted (or, misinterpreted) to cover a [very large number of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288367/which-option-in-the-current-close-vote-menu-should-be-used-for-questions-that-me#comment167357_288367) that don't actually come from a school assignment, thus opening it up to be abused for any question someone "doesn't like".

If a question is posted, well worded, shows research, and is in every other way a valid question, but is started with or ended with "this is homework" or "this is an assignment", simply remove the fluff text and *voila, it isn't a homework question anymore!*

Most of the samples you provided in your question are already covered by other close reasons.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself***. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

The fact that the question is asking for homework help vs hobby help vs work help shouldn't change the rules.

---

One thing that makes the above kinda shaky is this one line on the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic page:

> 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

I don't understand why the "for homework help" distinction is needed here. It should either apply to all questions or none of them.

Comment: *If a question is posted, well worded, shows research, and is in every other way a valid question, but is started with or ended with "this is homework" or "this is an assignment", simply remove the fluff text and voila, it isn't a homework question anymore!* That's all very nice, but that wasn't what my question was about at all. I specifically said I was talking about homework question askers that just copy-pasted their assignment questions verbatim, and not homework-related questions in general, which might in some cases be good questions.

Comment: Those typically fall under other close reasons already, or are perfectly valid questions. If one doesn't, then it probably doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: Adding an "other.." option or a "This is homework, please do the work yourself" option is just going to lead to closures that don't need to happen.

Comment: Here's an example. Say we come across a question that looks like this: **"Here is a Python list of data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Get the sum."**. This question can be reworded to: **"Here is a Python list of data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. How do I get the sum?"** and it would be a perfectly valid **and useful** question. Far more useful than the few thousand "here's my error, here's my code, it does this but it should do that" questions we get every day.

Comment: Why doesn't this fall into the scope of the rule ^H^H^H^H strong guideline that says "must include summary of the work you've done so far and the difficulty"?

Answer (score 3):

If close reasons for every edge case were added, Close Vote reviewers would spend all their time trying to choose the correct one (option paralysis), instead of actually reviewing the questions.

If you believe the question should be closed, pick the reason that's most appropriate, and move on with your life.

Comment: It's not really an edge case when it's one of the 6 examples of off-topic questions given on the page that explains what an off-topic question is. There are 6 clear examples given, and all of them *except* for the homework example are presented as options on the off-topic close dialog. It's conspicuous by its absence. When I first posted this question I thought it was just an oversight, but I'm starting to realize that there is a huge resistance to closing homework questions and lots of people would prefer if that reason was just removed from the help page altogether.

Comment: @samgak Ah, your point is that the close reasons don't match the ones listed in the FAQ, gotcha. There used a be a "question shows minimal understanding" but that was removed because it apparently hurt people's feelings (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257979/70345), and I'm guessing that's the same reason why homework currently isn't a close reason. Personally I've never understood the kid gloves approach to question moderation, particularly since "close" became "on hold".

Answer (score 2):

I came here to ask the same question, and feel that it is supported by

> 3) Questions asking for homework help **must** include a summary of the
>   work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

It's hard to find a reason that remotely matches this in the existing list.

Note that selecting the "wrong" reason can result in a strange looking reason comment being posted for the question, so it's not as simple as "just choose an existing one and get on with it".   This would only be helpful advice if there were a catch all reason.

I guess "blatantly off topic" is as close as it gets, since homework questions without anything other than copy and paste the question are blatantly in violation of this rule.

Comment: Well, that's actually not a hard-and-fast rule (we have *very* few of those), but an extremely strong suggestion. It is possible to ask a question inspired by homework, which is both high-quality and completely ignores that recommendation. Possible, but very rare and hard.

Comment: In which case, you wouldn't flag it, eh?    Doesn't help for flagging bad questions of this nature.   I guess they just get downvotes and move on... but the sad thing is that rep-seekers vote these up, presumably because they can get rep from answering them with the solution.   Maybe we need a separate site called homework exchange.  There's clearly demand...

Comment: No, they are closed for unclear (no idea what the "question" is), too broad (no idea where to start, or the starting point is obviously too low), debugging help (it doesn't work, write it for me) and the like. Naturally, if it's bad it will also be downvoted.

Comment: I guess you're saying this one is "too broad"?   That could work.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089366/finding-space-in-a-small-array-that-isnt-being-occupied

Comment: @Deduplicator The issue of whether the help center defines rules or guidelines seems like a red herring to me. If we are supposed to close according to a set of rules we should have close reasons that match the rules. If we close according to guidelines we should have close reasons that match the guidelines.

Comment: @samgak: You have to determine whether a question should be closed, and which close-reason covers it best. Yes, that's a question for your discretion, and not really a literal interpretation of "rules-as-written", which makes it hard, and means you should understand the *reasons* behind each one.

Comment: I still don't see why this is a reason _not_ to have a close-reason for an obvious case from the rules.

Comment: @Deduplicator I understand all that, but it seems like you are basically repeating the argument that we should make close vote decisions by following the guidelines according to our discretion, which I have no problem with. The problem is, once we have decided that a question is off-topic by consulting the guidelines and applying our discretion as to whether the question is good for the site, the available close options are less helpful than they could be. If a question is off-topic, why shoe-horn it into the "too broad" or "unclear" reasons? It just feels really unclear and imprecise.

Answer (score -2):

Every few months or so, the set of close reasons gets reduced because someone's feelings got hurt when their lousy question got closed.

This is a "race to the bottom" attempt to make SO as useful as Yahoo Answers.

I expect by this time next year, the only close reason will be "Contains Child Porn".