# Why isn't there a "Can I have the codes please?" flag option?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage

**This post is not meant as a suggestion. It is meant as a discussion as to the pros and cons of this imaginary flagging option.**

This question is distinct from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason) as I'm not asking why we should have one but why there isn't one. In an aged online community such as Stack Overflow it seems as though most everything has been thought of and I found it interesting that with so many of these questions on the site there has not been an option implemented for this.

I've just recently unlocked the review queues section of the site and after reading through [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) for triage review and sticking to it pretty closely (IE, I am still training myself to recognise what actions need to happen on each post and am skipping over the majority so as not to incorrectly categorise something).

I have seen a lot of questions which could have their titles replaced with "Can I have the codes please?" and would still make sense in the context of the content contained within the post. Lot's of "I have to do this, how?" or "Can someone give me a snippet for this?" etc.

I struggle to see a flagging option which matches up with these posts. As such we come back to my question.

Why isn't there a "Can I have the codes please?" flag option?

I'm curious as to whether this is something that has been considered in the past and I am unaware of this or whether this is something that would even work?

Does anyone have anything to input on why this would/wouldn't work and whether this has been talked about in the community before?

Comment: 99% of the time you can use an already existing close reason that also fits in order to close the question (too broad, unclear, mcve...).

Comment: @Keiwan In this case it's not just about closing the question, but also informing the user of why the question has been closed. It may be confused if in the comments people are saying "We're not going to code for you, try it yourself first" and then the close reason is "Too broad" although it may fit, it'd help to be clearer to the user so they can adjust.

Comment: I would say the duplicate and your question are ultimately the same thing even if you've expressed they're not, but I agree with you and it seems like (although back in 2014) the community agrees with adding that close reason, so I'd like to know why it hasn't been implemented? No saying that everything the community wants should be implemented but I can't see many cons with adding it

Comment: @George Agreed, if people are told one thing where the flag says another it can lead to confusion and further poor quality posts

Comment: @George I understand what you're saying but my point is that "You need to show something for us to work with" is a subset of "this question is too broad" so they shouldn't cause confusion. If they show an attempt instead of just requesting code out of nothing, then that makes the question a lot less broad for anyone who would try to answer it. I don't really see the point in adding another close option to the system that is ultimately covered by already existing ones.

Comment: @Keiwan But as in your flagged post, the top answers shows something which isn't too broad and isn't unclear but is still asking for code to be written for them. What acitons should be taken in those edge cases? As I see it, none of the current options fit the bill.

Comment: There is a [repository of pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136615/168333). Which includes a comment for "requirement dump" questions. You could use that to help new users understand the site better. (Tbh I think the wording of that one is still a bit harsh, at least for new users. You may want to tone it down).

Comment: Based on the fact that a lot of times when you see people ask these sort of code request questions the OPs have a lack of minimal understanding of the general problem itself, I don't necessarily agree that the question can't be regarded as too broad. Based on the question I have no reference point to know the level of knowledge of the OP and I therefore don't know where to start explaining the concepts that are required to understand the answer, thus making the answer potentially too long. On the other hand, if the question can be easily answered, is not a duplicate and will be useful to ...

Comment: ... future readers, then I don't see a reason to close it at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, flags like 'Take your dubious, copypasta homework requirements, do-my-work entitlement, selfish, uncaring attitude and shove the lot onto some other site where you stand a better chance of getting drones to slave for you' is politically incorrect.  So, 'Too broad' :)

Comment: @Keiwan Ok, taking your point into consideration. I get that if you do not have something to work from then you don't know the users current level of skill and can't answer something that is easily understandable and digestible. But if someone is asking "Can someone write this for me?" then no matter what their skill level is, surely that is not something which should be answered? Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, if someone is asking that, whether they are a master or a newbie, it shouldn't be answered on the site, right?

Comment: @MartinJames You might have just made my day

Comment: @EthanField well, if they just tried a bit, found some code and tried to compile/run it, posted the eror messages and, maybe, printed out a few var vaues as a debug aid, that would be just great.  A small display of effort goes a long way.

Comment: @MartinJames Agreed, my programming knowledge is not the greatest (It's a hobby, not a job for me) but I always resort to Stack Overflow as my last port of call if I'm truly stuck on something. And even then I try and phrase my questions in the most digestible and easily answered way possible.

Comment: TBH, I blame educators mostly.  It's like 'Programming 101, day one, write a client/server system for chats with linked-lists and stuff', when it should be 'Programming 101, day one, this is your IDE and the most important item that is integrated - the debugger'.

Comment: @EthanField You're right. "Can someone write this for me" is not even a proper question so in this case "Unclear what you're asking" applies as well. (This is the case for a lot of just pure code requests). [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260334/new-off-topic-closing-reason-programming-assignment) another discussion about whether all programming assignments questions should be closed (*"just because it's a programming assignment doesn't mean it's a bad question."*). And [here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/6214222) Shog's answer about zero-effort questions.

Comment: @MartinJames I blame educators too, but mostly for the fact that when I started my Comp Science course I was told to use Stack Overflow to help me out on the first day

Comment: _"lik in the picture, plz answer"_, there is no flag for them because we have enought flag on SO to handle them, and sometimes we can use Meta So flag when they come ranting about: "we re not helping" "we re getting payed" "why close" "why so mean why me" "Please giv me the cod i hav kidz"

Comment: If it was me, I would actually forbid new students to run code in any other way than by stepping line-by-line.  OK - let them use keyboard repeat to step quicker:)

Comment: @Keiwan Thank you, I see your point. I'm going to need to review more posts in Triage and follow your advice.

Comment: Educator are not the only one to blame, Something is wrong with parenting, when people show no respect to the one they are asking for advice.

Comment: LOL - I wonder if there's a market there - an IDE with the 'Run' icon and menu-item actually disabled;)

Comment: Every IDE are missing an important feature: Post the selection to SO.

Comment: @DragandDrop LOL, menu: 'Run, Step in, Step over, Pause, Stop, Post teh codez'

Comment: @MartinJames, Are those debug step? Are you crazy? If compilation fail when they press publish. You post on SO the input the dev wrote based on his understanding of the issue.

Comment: No real source or Error message is needed. No one read those. just a simple cut screen shoot of the selected area should be enought to make it a best seller.

Comment: Hehe......... )

Comment: @DragandDrop Don't even bother with the screenshot, just post a link to a local file "C:/MehCodez.py is broken, help"